# Block the app after installation by Google Protect

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-play-protect

When installing an application on **Android 7**, Google's protection system prevents it from installing and displays the following message:

> **Play Protect doesn't recognise this app's developer. Apps from unknown developers can sometimes be unsafe.**

How can i fix it?

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Oh yes, I remember asking question!
Thanks for you: @Pawel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Build Type tab. Select release mode and set:

**Signing Config to the config . (The one you just created).**

Sync your gradle . Enjoy!
[Android Build Types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnDWt.png)

Comment: That's exactly what I did not do!
thank you my friend

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's usually caused by an APK manually installed without downloading it from PlayStore.
The Protect informs the user about the potential problems about installing this kind of App.
You can disable the Protect from Android Settings page or (maybe) room the PlayStore Settings.

Comment: Maybe I'm not going to put the app on the Google store.
Does anyone who installs the app need to deactivate Google's protection? This is irrational! @emandt

Comment: No it's not required, but the user will redirected to an additional Activity where Protect informs about that da gerois thing. However the user have always the possibility to continue pressing a special button/link at the bottom.

Comment: Excuse me, but I did not notice your sayings.
I do not want to publish my app on Google and I also do not want the user to disable Google's protection system!
This problem arose a few days ago, and other developers have faced this problem. @emandt

Comment: I done an App and release OUTSIDE the PlayStore, and when I try to install the APK android shows me an additional Activity (the one provided from Play Protect) where it informs me about the "unsafe" App. I can press a "hyperlink" at the bottom and procede with the installation.